# Root console without a password with GRUB dual boot on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, security, passwords, grub, root

I just discovered that entering a recovery console (in Ubuntu 18.04.4 installed with a dual-boot alongside Windows) allows entering the root console without entering any password.
It seems to be a supermassive security black hole, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is intended for recovery purposes such as when you forget your password, still you can  prevent someone from accessing that root shell without password you can enable root account and set a password. Start ubuntu normally and log in to your account. Open Terminal. Now to this:

```
$ sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: new_root_password
Retype new UNIX password: confirm_root_password
passwd: Password updated successfully.
```

Now everytime you go to access the recovery root shell, you will need this root password and only you can use this root shell for special recovery and administration purposes.